# laravel display image in blade with echo function

Tags: php, laravel-blade

i tired display image in blade with echo function like :
echo "<img src='"{{ url('images/adult/'.$image.) }}'>";

give me syntax error, unexpected '<' (View:

Comment: `{{ }}` in blade is an echo (which gets replaced with php tags and an echo statement)... not sure why you are calling `echo` yourself ... would you like to show some more of your template?

Comment: You don't need to use `echo` in blade. To display some variable just use `{{$variable}}`

Comment: case i open folder to  read images inside it

Comment: what you have above is this `echo "<img src="<?php echo url('images/adult/'.$image); ?>'>";`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use echo in blade templates.

You can write html directly in the blade template and then use the double curly braces to inject your php.

So you'd be looking at something more like

```
<img src="{{ url('images/adult/' . $image) }}">
```